# Ecore EClass inheritance in Xtext

Tags: inheritance, xtext, ecore

Consider the following Ecore model (in Xcore notation):

```
class Foo {
    contains Element[] elements
}
class Bar extends Foo {
    int n
}
class Element {
    String name
}
```

and the following Xtext rules:

```
FooBar: Foo | Bar;
Foo: {Foo} 'foo' '{' elements+=Element (',' elements+=Element)* '}';
Foo: {Bar} 'bar' n=INT '{' elements+=Element (',' elements+=Element)* '}';
Element: {Element} name=ID;
```

such that textual models are like this:

```
foo {one, two}
bar 2 {three, four}
```

Is there a way to refactor the repetition away from the rules? I know I could introduce a new EClass `ElementContain` and make rules for `Foo` and `Bar` refer to its rule, however, that would clutter the metamodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally: no. but if the only difference is the first keyword:

```
FooBar:
 ({Foo} 'foo' | {Bar}'bar') '{' elements+=Element (',' elements+=Element)* '}';
Element: {Element} name=ID;
```

Comment: So if there are contexts where a `Bar` makes sense but a `Foo` does not, I am pretty much required to use composition instead of or in addition to inheritance?

Comment: Yes. There is no Templates/Fragments for Grammar Rules. Feel free to file an Enhancement Request into Eclipse Bugzilla